# Restrict access to single stream on keen

Tags: keen-io, access-keys

I have read access keys on keen.io And I have a use case where I would like to use these access keys. Actually, in my system, i want to make a separate stream for every customer account and want to make sure that this stream is only accessible (could be written/read) by that specific customer only. I want to use access keys for this purpose as I think it is their one of main use cases. 
Can anyone tell me how can I pass this information to an access key that it is only usable on a specific stream ONLY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would programmatically create an Access Key for each customer and set its permissions on creation so that it will autofill event properties with, for example, a customer id. With queries, you would set up the querying permissions with a filter so that it could only query event with that customer id.

Similar to the JSON in this example here: https://keen.io/docs/access/access-keys/#access-key-json-example

Then, any time that Access Key is used, it will **only** be able to query that specific data and all writes will include the autofill information that you set for that Access Key.